# Rewarded Video Black Screen

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I use the Rewarded Video Ads (Admob) but when rewired video is loaded, the menuitem in the toolbar becomes visible. Clicking menuitem rewarded.show() is active. Only a black screen appears on the screen. How do I solve this problem ?

MobileAds.initialize the settings was made.

IDE : Android Studio 3.3.1

Language : Kotlin

Lib : implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

Comment: Support your Question by code to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

In your Manifest (application level).

Comment: Same thing happens on my app, and its already with

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

In my app Manifest (application level).

The problem still happens.